# Accessing WordPress custom field in a new theme

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I've installed the "Enfold" theme (replacing RT Theme 13).  The old theme had a custom field for the product image location.  product_loop.php uses the following to insert the image

```
 <?php
          // Resize Portfolio Image
          $imgURL = find_image_org_path(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rt_product_image_url', true));
          $crop     = true;
          if($imgURL) $image_thumb = @vt_resize( '', $imgURL, 188, 0, ''.$crop.'' );
          ?>
```

Which references this function in functions.php:

```
if( ! function_exists("find_image_org_path") ){
    function find_image_org_path($image) {
        if(is_multisite()){
            global $blog_id;
            if (isset($blog_id) && $blog_id > 0) {
                if(strpos($image,get_bloginfo('wpurl'))!==false){//image is local 
                    if(empty(get_current_site(1)->path)){
                        $the_image_path = get_current_site(1)->path.str_replace(get_blog_option($blog_id,'fileupload_url'),get_blog_option($blog_id,'upload_path'),$image);
                    }else{
                        $the_image_path = $image;
                    }               
                }else{
                    $the_image_path = $image;
                }
            }else{
                $the_image_path = $image;
            }
        }else{
            $the_image_path = $image;
        } 

        return rt_clean_thumbnail_ext($the_image_path);
    }
}
```

If I remove the image call, the index page builds fine, but the index page breaks with this in place. I found a file called "product_custom_fields.php", with an array for "product_image_url" - am I on the right track?  What do I need to do to get these custom fields up & running in the Enfold theme?